# Getting nested properties dynamically

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I got a complex situation...

I am able to get a value via `$type->created_by->email`

- $type is an class (Entity) that contains data.
- created_by is a releation, so thats a class (Entity) too.
- email is a property of created_by; string.

When give my method the string 'title' (property of `$type`), my code will do `$type->$variable`  (where $variable is `title`).

This is what I want: I want to reach the `email` property via the `created_by` class.
I already tried `created_by->email`.

Someting like `created_by.email` as string-input would be nice...

How am I able to get properties of a class dynamically?

Thank you!

Comment: It would probably help if you'd explain what exactly your are talking about. Properties? What properties? What is `$type`?

Comment: @ndm I tried to explain it again... Thanks ;)

Comment: Where exactly do you need this type of access? Anywhere? In a controller? In a view? ...?

Comment: Well, I thought this is not a specific CakePHP related question... In my controller I give the string like `title`. The view will get `title` as variable so will do: `$type->$variable`;

Comment: Well, you are using CakePHP so for all I know you might be looking for a cake-ish solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is there such functionality available at entity level (there have been attempts to implement this **[[1]](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/7847)**, **[[2]](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/11792)**), nor is this something that PHP would support out of the box.

Generally you would have to iterate over the properties. You can find something like that in the entity context for the form helper, see [**`EntityContext::val()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/b7429be2147c2628f0f2454d4ee3e831ffb561f0/src/View/Form/EntityContext.php#L200) for some inspiration.

A quick solution would be to utilize [**`Hash::get()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html#Cake%5CUtility%5CHash::get).

```
// in CakePHP versions before 3.1.0 you'd have to convert
// the entity to an array first using $entity->toArray()
Hash::get($entity, 'dot.notated.path')
```

You could for example implement this in a custom method in a base entity class that all your other entities extend.

Comment: `Hash::get($entity->toArray(), 'dot.notated.path')` is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

Comment: EntityInterface extends from ArrayAccess, so Hash::get() would work fine direct on the entity. So the toArray() is not necessary

(came here from google, so sorry for resurrecting this old thread)

Comment: @Nat No problem, `ArrayAccess` compatibilty has been added to `Hash::get()` in CakePHP 3.1.0, I've updated the answer to reflect that.